# Properties of high frequency sinusoids.

Tags: trigonometry

what can I say about

$$\sin(sx) + \sin(qx)$$

for s,q sufficiently large? I can obviously bound it above and below by 2 and -2, is there anything better I can do? assuming that s,q is sufficiently large?

Comment: Large s,q are no different from small in this regard. Your function will come arbitrarily close to +2 and -2. The rest depends on whether $s/q$ is rational.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bound it by constants, not generally, but for some specific values of $q$ and $s$ yes you can.
First of all, you have the identity $\sin(sx) + \sin(qx) = 2\sin((q+s)x/2) \cos((q-s)x/2)$.  So really, it's easier to work in terms of $a = (q+s)/2$ and $b = |q-s|/2$.  And then it's easier to make the transformation $y = ax , \ c = b/a$, so your function turns into $2 \sin(y) \cos(cy)$.

If $c$ is irrational, then it will get arbitrarily close to $2$ and $-2$ infinitely often (that is, for any $\epsilon > 0$, the set $\{x \ | \ 2 - \epsilon < \sin(sx) + \sin(qx) < 2\}$ has infinite measure, and so does the set close to $-2$).

If $c$ is rational, things get more interesting.  In order for the function to achieve a maximum of $2$, we need $\sin(y) = \cos(cy) \in \{-1, 1\}$.  Which means that $y = (2m+1)\pi /2$ and $cy = n\pi$ for some integers $m,n$ (which are both even or both odd).  So $c = (2m+1)/n$.  So in particular, if $c$ is of the form $p/q$, with $p,q$ relatively prime and $p$ even, the function can't hit $2$.  Likewise it can't hit $-2$.  If on the other hand, $p$ is odd, then the function will hit $\pm 2$ infinitely often.

I'd suggest playing around with different values of $c$ with an even numerator and seeing what you can see.